# Combining two taxonomy terms in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to combine two taxonomy terms together in wordpress. I have an taxonomy called area and another called city and the area is attached to the city.

So i have the output of terms to appear as follows:

New York
Area 1 (2)
Area 2 (3)
Area 3 (1)

London
Area B (1)

I have managed to get the areas listed with the code below, however i am not able to separate them by city.

php:

```
function curaareacityShortcode() {
$terms = get_terms('property_area'); 
$cura_city = get_terms('property_city'); 
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){ 

echo '<ul>'; 
echo $cura_city;

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
 $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'property_area' ); 
 $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'property_area' ); 

  echo '<li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="padding-right:15px"></i><a   href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ')' . '</a></li>'; 
} 
echo '</ul>';
}

}
```

Comment: how did you create this relation between both taxonomies? afaik wordpress does not provide this, you had to do this with custom code or some plugin, right?

Comment: the connection was created by having the city to be the parent of the area. `term_meta[cityparent]`

Comment: well, so use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/ to see what is the city id, then handle it as you want (you did not describe what specifically you want to achieve)